# TFS Sprint Item Print Plug-in

Tags: tfs, plugins, scrum

Does anyone know if there is a plug-in for TFS that will print out our sprint backlog items in a format suitable for using on a Scrum Board, rather than us having to write them out by hand?

Answer (score 4):

If your setup is Team Foundation Server 2010/2012/2013 with the Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum process template or the MSF for Agile Software Development process template, this project can help you.

https://github.com/frederiksen/Task-Card-Creator

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I read your question right, perfect tool right here:

http://blog.crisp.se/henrikkniberg/2007/12/18/1197973740000.html

An excel template you can use to print your backlog off.  All you need to do is pull down your work items from TFS into excel, then print 'em off.  Not exactly a "plug-in" but I use it for every sprint.

BTW, that blog, and the paper he references are the Scrum Bible, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Where do you put the "How to Demo" field in TFS?

Answer (score 1):

We have successfully used a combination of a custom query, the right click -> "Open in Microsoft Excel" and a Word mail merge to print out cards for our scrum board.  That lets us define exactly what we want displayed for the stories and tasks.  The only downside is we cut the paper and tape it up instead of using sticky notes.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a similar tool a while back, and we ended up just putting everything on cards & sticking them to a whiteboard.

Much easier view into our progress... however that status doesn't get into TFS unless we update it :)