# TFS visualstudio.com print or export?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, scrumboard

I would like to be able to print the backlog of the current sprint to view the progress. The thing is that the webbased Team foundation service is not very suitable for print.

I also did not find an option to export to Microsoft project.

I prefer to stick with an all microsoft solution. How do other people work with the webbased TFS

I really like the 21 october update but I cannot seem to find the print option.
http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/2013-oct-21

It seems that I am the only one missing the print feature: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/30925-team-foundation-server 
So I think that I am doing something wrong.

ps. is this a question for stackoverflow or [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: "is this a question for stackoverflow or programmers", I think you're in the right place. The [about] page says "Software development tools" is on topic here.

Comment: my question looks a bit the same as this old question from back in 2008. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211488/tfs-sprint-item-print-plug-in?rq=1 So I really have the feeling that I am missing a feature. or that I am using it wrong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are third party solutions to allow you to connect to TFS from Word, but if you want to stick with an all Microsoft solution I would suggest using the [Excel plug-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You could use it to bring the content of a query into Excel, the format and print the results. It is installed along with Visual Studio or Team Explorer.

> A Team Foundation add-in is installed into each of the following
>   Microsoft Office products when you install any edition of Visual
>   Studio 2012 or Visual Studio Team Explorer 2012. The add-in requires
>   Office 2007 version or later.

Comment: Or just export the backlog to Excel and print. If you want it formatted consistently however, the Excel plug-in is what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have just downloaded 2013 team explorer http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832116&clcid=0x409

Answer (score 1):

There is now a separate download (Microsoft Team Foundation Server Office Integration 2015 Update 1) that does not require a full VS install, available here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49992